# Remove array from array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have 2 arrays like this:

`$array1 = @('Item10', 'Item20', 'Item30', 'Item40')`

`$array2 = @('Item1', 'Item3')`

I would like to have my final array like this:

`$arrayfinal = @('Item30', 'Item40')`

meaning: find 'like' Item1 from array2 in array1, so remove it !

I tried: with the '-like' operator, the '-ne' operator, tried to add '*' and use the 'like' operator but could not find what I want.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm having problems following your question due to the example you give.. Both arrays have no element in common, so why you would end up with just the last two elements of $array1 is beyond me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test each value in `$array1` against each possible prefix from `$array2` until you get a match (or not) - in other words, *nested filters*.

My preferred approach is to nest `.Where({...}, 'First')` inside `Where-Object`:

```
$arrayfinal = $array1 |Where-Object {$item = $_; -not $array2.Where({$item -like "${_}*"}, 'First')}
```

The `'First'` mode will make `.Where()` return as soon as the first item satisfies the condition, thereby not needlessly going through all of `$array2` on each iteration.

Comment: It seems the OP wants to retain only the elements of $array1 which are NOT like elements in $array2, so the negation should be added in front of the filter condition: `$arrayfinal = $array1 |Where-Object {$item = $_; ! $array2.Where({$item -like "${_}*"}, 'First')}`

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I got it mixed up because of OPs impossible final array example. Fixed